# How many skew symmetric matrices are possible?

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, permutations

I just heard the term skew symmetric matrix and upon discovering what it was, I thought to myself, "Jeez, there could only be so many of those."

I'm not good with the whole permutation thing and this is a new concept to me, I don't know the rules. So, I convey this question to you.
**How many skew-symmetric matrices of order $ m \times n$ are possible?**

Comment: What, like over $\Bbb R$? Even $\begin{bmatrix}0&r\\-r&0\end{bmatrix}$ for each $r\in \Bbb R$ gives you infinitely many...

Comment: Only square matrices can be skew symmetric, what do you mean by "order $m\times n$"?

Comment: for those of us who are good with "the whole permutation thing" but not good with matrices, redefine the term skew symmetric matrix please? Yes of course, I *could* search google, but be a good boy.

Comment: @Sabyasachi $A^T = -A$ (as opposed to "just" symmetric, which is $A^T = A$)

Comment: "be a good boy"? Either there's a language barrier here, or you're being incredibly patronising.

Comment: @gt6989b that's infinite of course. and agreeing with 5xum now. Because I am not fresh on definitions, $m \times n$ confused me. I thought it has to be square anyway, which apparently it *has* to be.

Comment: @Sabyasachi *of course* it must be square. But there is still uncountably infinitely many.

Comment: Take a square matrix $M$. Then $M-M^T$ is skew symmetric, because $(M-M^T)^T=M^T-M=-(M-M^T)$

Comment: @DanielLittlewood i know him(over chat and stuff). I was kidding.

Comment: The case $m=n=1$ looks good, there's only one such matrix and I'm even not good with "the whole permutation thing".

Comment: @Sabyasachi Alright, fair enough!

Answer (score 2):

Well, knowing the upper half fixes the lower half so you can pick values for the upper half and the main diagonal. There is an uncountable infinity of those, even for $2 \times 2$ matrices, because you can pick any of the values in an uncountable infinity of choices, and you got more than 1 of those values to pick :-).

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking at $n\times n$ matrices over a finite ring of order $q$, then you are free to pick the entries above the diagonal to be whatever you want. The rest are then determined, and you get a skew-symmetric matrix.

There are $n^2$ total entries, $n^2-n$ nondiagonal entries, and so $(n^2-n)/2$ entries above the diagonal. There are $q$ choices to be made in each spot, so that gives you a total of $q^{\frac{n^2-n}{2}}$ skew symmetric matrices over the finite ring.

If the ring you have is infinite, then you can still produce skew-symmetric matrices the same way, and you'll have infinitely many.